# How to make special regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex

In my project I would like to implement special regex for string.
For ex: I need HypervisorName like "hvm01" first letters then numbers.
I used regex like below:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^(([a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.)*([A-Za-z]|[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0- 
9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])$", ErrorMessage = "Virtual Machine name is not formatted correctly")]
```

But I am still able to add name like "test" but in my case I need both together first letter then number.

Comment: add the following in the end of your statement and it would require at least one digit [0-9]+

Comment: @DmitriTsoy after $ symbol?

Comment: just before the $

Comment: is `123` or `hyper` is valid string? string or number optional? or string must have string as well as number? Can you show us inputs and expected output(Test cases)

Comment: @DmitriTsoy works fine now

Comment: looks too complex please check my answer how to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you change the regex to something like `^[a-z]{3,}\\d{2,}$` and use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`?

This will check that there are minimum three letters `[a-z]{3,}` at the start `^` on the string followed by the minimum 2 digits `\\d{2,}` and the end of the string `$`.

You can limit max number of letters by second option in the {} brackets, like `[a-z]{3, 10}` means min 3 and max 10 letters

```
var r = new Regex("^[a-z]{3,}\\d{2,}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

matched: hostname123
wrong match: h1
matched: HHH12
wrong match: HHH 12
wrong match: host name
wrong match: host name123
```

Comment: In my case I didn't mention about strongly secure but this approach good!